# Flutter Hello world app can't start on Android Emulator x86_64

Tags: flutter

I am currently working on Xamarin Forms and want to try Flutter.
I created a Flutter project with Android Studio. But I can't run it.
I get this error on Android Emulator
Error launching the application on Android SDK built for x86 64.

flutter doctor looks fine. 
some example app like Flutter Gallery can work but some can't.

The platform is Windows 10 64 bit. 
Android Studio 3.2.1

Error Message is:

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug
>   mode...
>  Initializing gradle...
>  Resolving dependencies...
>   Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>  Built
>   build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
>  Installing
>   build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
>  Error: ADB exited with exit code
>   1
>  adb: failed to install 
>   C:\Users\xxx\source\flutter\flutter_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk:
>   Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86 64.
>
> C:\flutter>flutter doctor
>  Doctor summary (to see all details, run
>   flutter doctor -v):
>  [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on
>   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.472], locale zh-TW)
>  [√]
>   Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   28.0.3)
>  [√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
>  [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
>  [!] VS Code, 64-bit edition
>   (version 1.30.1)
>  [!] Connected device
>       ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from those lines:

```
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

You are missing the plugin for flutter and dart.

Go to:

```
File -> Settings -> Plugins
```

and install Flutter

[image]

And check to see if dart was installed as well 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. The error message of flutter doctor belong to IntelliJ IDEA not Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated IntelliJ IDEA plugin and revise my questions

Comment: You asked for android studio "I create flutter project with Android Studio.".
So can I get up vote or even better accepted answer to my answer?.

Comment: dart and flutter had installed in Android Studio with latest version. I have no idea why some example can work, but some can't. Could be Android Studio config problem. but I can't figure out.

Comment: @chunhunghan Have you solved the issue? I am having similar problem :- Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.

Comment: I did not solve this problem. I just reinstall everything to make it work.